# Can not reach the pods on VirtualBox virtual machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing

I have a deployment scaled to 4 replicas running in 3 machines. 1 master machine, 1 another physical machine, and 1 VirtualBox machine on the master machine. So I have 3 nodes in total. I scaled my deployment with 4 replicas, Kubernetes distributed 4 pods as 2 pods per worker node. I exposed the deployment to the internet using `kubectl expose deployment/<my_deployment> --type="NodePort" --port 8080`. When I use `curl <cluster_ip>:$NODE_PORT` Kubernetes load balances the requests successfully but when the nodes on the VirtualBox machine is accessed it prints:

> `curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.28 port 32648: Connection timed out`.

The other nodes on the other physical machine are responding well.
What can be the problem here?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add the IP addresses of all machines and how they are interconnected

Comment: master -----> 192.168.1.28
VirtualBox --> 10.0.2.15
Other machine ---> 192.168.1.35
All physical machines are in the same network.

Comment: It doesn't seem like they're on the same VLan, did you configure the VM with *bridge* network card?

Comment: I have 2 physical machines at my home, using wireless communication. I configured VM network as NAT. When I change it to bridge network,   `kubectl` commands prints `unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.1.28:6443: connect: no route to host`.  In NAT configuration `kubectl` works well.

Comment: I don't know if this info is useful but master machine uses a USB wireless adapter. VM resides in master machine.

Comment: Is it the VB machine using NAT networking?

Comment: Yes it is configured as NAT networking.

Comment: The problem is solved by configuring networking as bridge and restarting the VM. Thank you all.